# Avoiding busy waiting in bash, without the sleep command

Tags: bash, shell-script, sleep

I know I can wait on a condition to become true in bash by doing:

```
while true; do
  test_condition && break
  sleep 1
done
```

But it creates 1 sub-process at each iteration (sleep).  I could avoid them by doing:

```
while true; do
  test_condition && break
done
```

But it uses lot of CPU (busy waiting).  To avoid sub-processes and busy waiting, I came up with the solution bellow, but I find it ugly:

```
my_tmp_dir=$(mktemp -d --tmpdir=/tmp)    # Create a unique tmp dir for the fifo.
mkfifo $my_tmp_dir/fifo                  # Create an empty fifo for sleep by read.
exec 3<> $my_tmp_dir/fifo                # Open the fifo for reading and writing.

while true; do
  test_condition && break
  read -t 1 -u 3 var                     # Same as sleep 1, but without sub-process.
done

exec 3<&-                                # Closing the fifo.
rm $my_tmp_dir/fifo; rmdir $my_tmp_dir   # Cleanup, could be done in a trap.
```

Note: in the general case, I cannot simply use `read -t 1 var` without the fifo, because it will consume stdin, and will not work if stdin is not a terminal or a pipe.

Can I avoid sub-processes and busy waiting in a more elegant way ?

Comment: `true` is a builtin and does not create a sub process in bash. busy waiting will always be bad.

Comment: @joranm: you are right about `true`, question updated.

Comment: Why not without fifo? Simply `read -t 1 var`.

Comment: @ott: you are right, but this will consume stdin.  Also, it will not work if stdin is not a terminal or a pipe.

Comment: If maintainability is an issue, I'd would strongly suggest going with the `sleep` as in the first example. The second one, while it may work, is not going to be easy for anyone to adjust in the future.  Simple code also have bigger _potential_ for being safe.

Comment: If stdin is closed but stdout or stderr is still open it is possible to do "exec <&1/2", although I don't know how portable that is.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In newer versions of `bash` (at least v2), builtins may be loaded (via `enable -f filename commandname`) at runtime. A number of such loadable builtins is also distributed with the bash sources, and `sleep` is among them. Availability may differ from OS to OS (and even machine to machine), of course. For example, on openSUSE, these builtins are distributed via the package [`bash-loadables`](https://software.opensuse.org/package/bash-loadables).

Comment: Wow, this is what I am looking for, and I definitely learn something about loadable builtin: +1.  I will try this, and yet it is the best answer.

Comment: It works !  On debian, the package is bash-builtins.  It only includes sources and the Makefile must be edited, but I was able to install `sleep` as a builtin.  Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Creating a lot of subprocesses is a bad thing in an inner loop. Creating one `sleep` process per second is OK. There's nothing wrong with

```
while ! test_condition; do
  sleep 1
done
```

If you really want to avoid the external process, you don't need to keep the fifo open.

```
my_tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
trap 'rm -rf "$my_tmpdir"' 0
mkfifo "$my_tmpdir/f"

while ! test_condition; do
  read -t 1 <>"$my_tmpdir/f"
done
```

Comment: You are right about a process per second being peanuts (but my question was about finding a way to remove it).  About the shorter version, It is nicer than mine, so +1 (but I removed the `mkdir` as it is done by `mktemp` (if not, it is a race condition)).  Also true about the `while ! test_condition;` which is nicer than my initial solution.

Answer (score 10):

I recently had a need to do this. I came up with the following function that will allow bash to sleep forever without calling any external program:

```
snore()
{
    local IFS
    [[ -n "${_snore_fd:-}" ]] || { exec {_snore_fd}<> <(:); } 2>/dev/null ||
    {
        # workaround for MacOS and similar systems
        local fifo
        fifo=$(mktemp -u)
        mkfifo -m 700 "$fifo"
        exec {_snore_fd}<>"$fifo"
        rm "$fifo"
    }
    read ${1:+-t "$1"} -u $_snore_fd || :
}
```

NOTE: I previously posted a version of this that would open and close the file descriptor each time, but I found that on some systems doing this hundreds of times a second would eventually lock up. Thus the new solution keeps the file descriptor between calls to the function. Bash will clean it up on exit anyway.

This can be called just like /bin/sleep, and it will sleep for the requested time. Called without parameters, it will hang forever.

```
snore 0.1  # sleeps for 0.1 seconds
snore 10   # sleeps for 10 seconds
snore      # sleeps forever
```

[There's a writeup with excessive details on my blog here](https://blog.dhampir.no/content/sleeping-without-a-subprocess-in-bash-and-how-to-sleep-forever)

Comment: Excellent blog entry. However, I went there looking for an explanation why `read -t 10 < <(:)` returns immediately while `read -t 10 <> <(:)` waits the full 10 seconds, but I still don’t get it.

Comment: In `read -t 10 <> <(:)` what does `<>` stand for?

Comment: <> opens the file descriptor for reading and writing, even though the underlying process substitution <(:) only allows reading. This is a hack that causes Linux, and Linux specifically, to assume someone might write to it, so read will hang waiting for input that will never arrive. It will not do this on BSD systems, in which case the workaround will kick in.

Comment: Just `read -t 10 <> <(:)` without creating unique file descriptors beforehand seems to be working fine with multiple concurrent calls (linux, bash 4.1)

Comment: See the "NOTE" I posted for why I'm not doing that. On some systems, mainly the Raspberry Pi's I was testing it on, they locked up after a few thousand calls. Some bug I didn't want to track down. Keeping the descriptor open also saves on processing power, as your call to (:) will spawn a subshell each time. It exits immediately, sure, but it's still spawned.

Comment: @bolt Is there any way to cancel the infinite snore? I trap the SIGTERM signal, and want to cancel the snore from there, else the script will not exit by itself. So is there some command I can use that will end the snore?

Comment: @Maestro it is blocked on IO, so not easy. Perhaps you can adapt the formula using a fifo, as it is already for macOS, but without "forgetting" and deleting fifo. Then you can echo a blank line to wake all those sleeping.

Comment: @Maestro try this.
`wakey_wakey() { [[ -v _snore_fd ]] && echo >&$_snore_fd || :; }`

Comment: Also, check the blog post for an updated function, as the latest versions of bash cause the subshell to hang around until the first time you finish reading from it. ...in case you care about that subshell.

Answer (score 4):

As user **yoi** said, if in your script is *stdin* opened, then instead of *sleep 1* you can simply use:

```
read -t 1 3<&- 3<&0 <&3
```

In Bash version 4.1 and newer you can use float number, e.g. `read -t 0.3 ...`

If in a script *stdin* is closed (script is called `my_script.sh < /dev/null &`), then you need use another opened descriptor, which not produces output when *read* is executed, eg. *stdout*:

```
read -t 1 <&1 3<&- 3<&0 <&3
```

If in a script all descriptor is closed (*stdin*, *stdout*, *stderr*) (e.g. because is called as daemon), then you need find any exists file which not produces output:

```
read -t 1 </dev/tty10 3<&- 3<&0 <&3
```

Comment: `read -t 1 3<&- 3<&0 <&3` is the same as `read -t 0`. It's just reading from from stdin with timeout.

Answer (score 3):

In `ksh93` or `mksh`, `sleep` is a shell builtin, so an alternative might be to use those shells instead of `bash`.

`zsh` also has a `zselect` builtin (loaded with `zmodload zsh/zselect`) that can sleep for a given number of hundredths of seconds with `zselect -t <n>`.

Answer (score 2):

This works from a login shell as well as a non-interactive shell.

```
#!/bin/sh

# to avoid starting /bin/sleep each time we call sleep, 
# make our own using the read built in function
xsleep()
{
  read -t $1 -u 1
}

# usage
xsleep 3
```

Comment: This also worked on Mac OS X v10.12.6

Comment: This is not recommended. If multiple scripts use this at the same time then they all get SIGSTOP'ed as they all try to read stdin. Your stdin gets blocked while this waits. Don't use stdin for this. You want new different file descriptors.

Comment: @Normadize There is another answer here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407383/147685) that deals with the concern of using free file descriptors. Its bare minimum version is `read -t 10 <> <(:)`.

Comment: @Amir consider that the <(:) will create a subshell , so its not free ...

Comment: `read` always returns "bad exitcode" though, and using a `read -t 1 && true` beats the purpose because now you're calling the `true` binary. So no, I don't think it works.

Answer (score 1):

A slight improvement on the above mentioned solutions (which I have based this on).

```
bash_sleep() {
    read -rt "${1?Specify sleep interval in seconds}" -u 1 <<<"" || :;
}

# sleep for 10 seconds
bash_sleep 10
```

Reduced the need for a fifo and hence no cleaning up to do.

Comment: This is not recommended. If multiple scripts use this at the same time then they all get SIGSTOP'ed as they all try to read stdin. Your stdin gets blocked while this waits. Don't use stdin for this. You want new different file descriptors.

Comment: @Normadize Never thought of that; please can you elaborate or point me to a resource where I can read more about it.

Comment: @CodeMedic There is another answer here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407383/147685) that deals with the concern of using free file descriptors. Its bare minimum version is `read -t 10 <> <(:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a fifo? Redirecting stdin to another file descriptor should work as well.

```
{
echo line | while read line; do
   read -t 1 <&3
   echo "$line"
done
} 3<&- 3<&0
```

Inspired by: [Read input in bash inside a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6883363)

Comment: This is not doing a sleep, this is still consuming stdin from the terminal.