# what's the max number accepted by sleep?

Tags: sleep

I want to run some jobs after waiting some time:

I can do:

```
sleep 1000;foo-1;foo-2
```

What I expected is to wait couple of hours, `sleep` seems not the best solution.

and I don't want to setup cron job.

Comment: [GNU sleep](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sleep-invocation.html) accepts [`inf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Floating-point.html#Floating-point). Which `sleep` are you using?

Comment: should be /bin/sleep, I use it directly in the shell.

Comment: You may not want a cron job.  But have you considered `at` ?

Comment: I didn't know this before, looks good.

Comment: @user10489, you should write an answer :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell: is it possible to delay a command without using \`sleep\`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482725/shell-is-it-possible-to-delay-a-command-without-using-sleep)

Comment: Why do you think that _sleep seems not the best solution_?

Comment: What is your question? The title asks for how long one may sleep with `sleep`, while the body of the question seems to ask for something else.

Answer (score 3):

POSIX states:

> As with all other utilities that take integral operands and do not specify subranges of allowed values, `sleep` is required […] to deal with time requests of up to 2147483647 seconds.

<sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sleep.html))</sup>

2147483647 seconds is over 68 years. Implementations are allowed to support larger numbers. Unless your OS is extremely obscure, you can expect your `sleep` to be able to reliably sleep for up to about 68 years.

What if your OS is extremely obscure? Consider a *hypothetical* implementation of `sleep` that is limited to 16-bit signed integer. The maximum value would be 32767 seconds, it's over 9 hours. Even this `sleep` would be able to wait "couple of hours".

I can imagine even more limited `sleep`. 8-bit values would allow at most 255 (if unsigned) or 127 (if signed) seconds. It's literally a couple of minutes. I doubt anyone ever implemented so limited `sleep`.

The conclusion is: to wait couple of hours, `sleep` is a decent solution. Technically it will work.