# bash trap of SIGTERM fails

Tags: bash

I have a very simple script to trap signals:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
unlink SigTermRecieved
unlink SigIntRecieved
#trap " touch SigTermRecieved ; exit " SIGTERM                                  
trap " touch SigIntRecieved ; exit " SIGINT
echo "pid is $$"
while true
do
    sleep 60m
done
exit
```

BEHAVIOR

with both trap lines commented:
  SIGTERM sent: terminates program.
? SIGINT sent from another terminal window is IGNORED!
  CTRL C terminates program.

with SIGTERM trap uncommented:
? SIGTERM sent: program does not terminate and SIGTERM trap is not executed.
? SIGINT sent from another terminal window is IGNORED!
  CTRL C terminates program.

with SIGINT trap uncommented:
  SIGTERM sent: terminates program.
? SIGINT from another terminal window is IGNORED!
  CTRL C executes trap code and terminates program.

The behaviors preceded by ? are unexpected or wrong. I'm not too concerned about the SIGINT behaviors. I tried those to see if any traps would work.

So, I removed the snooze function and just have:

```
sleep 60m &
wait $!
```

Now, `kill -TERM -pid` kills both processes and executes the trap for SIGTERM.

In my application, I'm waiting for SIGTERM from system shutdown, so I can clean up some details. I don't know whether system shutdown uses `pid` or `-pid`, both work for me, and the system will eventually kill all the processes. A few dangling sleep processes while I'm testing is no big deal.

That fifo solution is quite complicated and I don't understand it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

[In the comments below, keep in mind that `bash` (or any other shell) is a C program, which may set a handler for a signal even when the script sets no trap for it]

> with both trap lines commented:
>   `SIGTERM` sent: terminates program.

Since `bash` does not set any handler for `SIGTERM`, that signal will kill it outright, causing the shell it was started from to return the prompt. But the `sleep` command, which is an external program and runs in a separate child process, will continue to run (`pgrep -a sleep` to verify).

> ? `SIGINT` sent from another terminal window is IGNORED!

When waiting for a child process (as `sleep` in this case), `bash` sets a signal handler for `SIGINT`, and if no trap was set for it, will ignore that signal, except for the case where the child process it's waiting for terminates because of the same signal. `bash` is able to gather from the exit status of the child whether it was killed by a signal, and which signal it was.

That's the so-called "wait and cooperative exit" ([WCE](https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html)) and only applies to the `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` signals.

Other shells may not do that, and may simply delay acting on the `SIGINT` signal until the child they wait for has terminated. Example comparing `bash` and `dash`:

```
$ ( (sleep .2; pkill -INT -P $$)&); dash -c 'while :; do /bin/sleep 3; done'
<dash is killed by a self-raised SIGINT after 3 seconds>

$ ( (sleep .2; pkill -INT -P $$)&); bash -c 'while :; do /bin/sleep 3; done'
^C
<bash has to be killed by hand with Control-C>
```

> `CTRL C` terminates program.

A `Ctrl-C` will cause the *kernel* to send a `SIGINT` signal to *all* the processes from the foreground process group (job), which in this case include *both* your script and its `sleep` child. You can simulate that by using the `kill` command with the *negated* pid of the *process group leader* (the same as the process group id), or by using the `kill` shell builtin with the job id:

```
bash -c 'sleep 3600; echo DONE' &
[1] 12381
kill -INT -12381  # or kill -INT %1
```

Using the negated pid of the script only works when it really is the *process group leader*. That may not the case when the script was called from a subshell or another script, or as part of a pipeline.

> with `SIGTERM` trap uncommented:
>   ? `SIGTERM` sent: program does not terminate and `SIGTERM` trap is not executed.

Yes, the trap will be executed. But only after the `sleep` command has terminated. Use `sleep 1` instead of `sleep 60m` if you don't want to wait 60 minutes to confirm it ;-)

This was also explained in the linked answer, and it's a [standard-required](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11) behavior.

> with `SIGINT` trap uncommented:
>   ? `SIGINT` from another terminal window is IGNORED!

Ditto.

Comment: So, is there a way to sleep that is interruptible by SIGTERM?

Comment: Yes, kill the sleep process, too.

Comment: You may also try using a fifo, an doing a timed read on it: `bash -c 'echo $$; mkfifo fifo; exec 3<>fifo; while :; do read -t2 <fifo; echo
next; done'`. You may also get some other ideas (not all great) [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68236/avoiding-busy-waiting-in-bash-without-the-sleep-command)

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution.

```
function snooze {
    sleep $1
}

while true
do
    snooze 60m &
    wait $!
done
```

This will execute the trap then terminate immediately after receiving SIGTERM.

Thanks for your assistance.